# jQuery Scroll not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I current have a jQuery setup to add a .sticky attribute to my header once the user has scrolled past 300px:

```js
// Sticky header
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
                jQuery(".cust_sticky_header").addClass('sticky');
            } else {
                jQuery(".cust_sticky_header").removeClass('sticky');
            }
        });
```

It's been working fine until last night when I went to change some of the menu headings in  my primary navigation, after which it only seems to trigger on the homepage. I can't see any reason why changing this would effect the trigger and have spent several hours trying to figure it out, with no luck. The class of the header which should have the .sticky applied has not changed from what is referenced in the trigger.

Has anyone else run into this issue and knows a fix? I have developed my site using **Wordpress**. No plugins have been updated which may be the cause and I have reset the menu to a state when it was working, however the **jQuery** continues to work only on the homepage. I have temporarily set the header to be sticky using **Elementor**, however it is not a perfect fix (no transition animation, doesn't work on the "shop" page, etc.) and I would like to get it back working how it was.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour should work. There should be some style issues by which the window's scroll is being blocked.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
        jQuery(".cust_sticky_header").addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        jQuery(".cust_sticky_header").removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.cust_sticky_header {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cust_sticky_header">Sticky header</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
<div>Some content to scroll</div>
```